# Check type of items in list are all same and perform task

Tags: python, string, list, types, integer

I want to be able to create a function that takes a list, checks if every item in the list is of a certain type (one item at a time) and if so, perform the calculation. For this particular function, I want to calculate the product of a list of integers.

My function:

```
def multpoly(items):
    typeInt = []
    total = 1
    for i in list:
        if type(i) is int:
            total = total * i
        elif type(i) is str:
            typelist.append(i)
        elif type(i) is list:
            typelist.append(i)
    return total
    return listInt

items = [1,2,3,4,5]
stringitems = ["1","2","3"]
listitems = [[1,1],[2,2]]

print(multpoly(items))
print(multpoly(stringitems))
print(multpoly(listitems))
```

I would also like to be able to create functions to do the same, changing the list to a list of strings and joining them and changing the list to a list of lists and concatenating them.

This current function doesn't work. I receive an error - "'type' object is not iterable".

If anyone could suggest fixes or could explain what's going on that would be great! :)

Comment: Could you provide output samples for each request you made?

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to iterate `list`, but the argument is named `items`. Also, `i` would be an `int`, but it wouldn't actually be `int` itself; you'd want `isinstance(i, int)` or `type(i) is int`. Lastly, you can't add a `str` to an `int`(`total`); if the goal is to fail when any item is not an `int`, you need to handle that when the type check fails (otherwise you'll skip the item, but still report that the list was all integers). You probably want code more like this:

```
# This uses the Py3 style print function, accessible in Py2 if you include
from __future__ import print_function
# at the top of the file. If you want Py2 print, that's left as an exercise

class NotUniformType(TypeError): pass

def multpoly(items):
    total = 1
    for i in items:
        if not isinstance(i, int):
            raise NotUniformType("{!r} is not of type int".format(i))
        total *= i
    return total

try:
    print(multpoly(items), "Items in list are integers"))
except NotUniformType as e:
    print("Items in list include non-integer types:", e)
```

Comment: I want to be able to check the type of the list, and perform a task based on the type of the list. E.g, if list is all integers, calculate the product of the list, or if the list is all strings, print out the strings after one another. I'll update my code and show you what I have.

Comment: @ChrisMulheron: If it does completely different things dependent on the type, just write different functions. The problem is that you can't uniformly handle cases like the empty `list`, and it's completely unclear what a reasonable response to a heterogeneous `list` should be. Even in your updated code, none of your variables are used with consistent names, you have multiple `return`s only one of which executes, etc. It's completely nonsensical.